# How do i make my code for my helper more slim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

First of all i am new to asking questions on stackoverflow. If you downvote this question please let me know why and how i can change it.

So i am working on a status webpage for our intern services.

This is the code i have and to be clear i want to make the method "most_recent_checkresult_ids" more slim:

```
  1 class OverallStatus
  2   def initialize(check_ids)
  3     @check_ids = check_ids
  4   end
  5
  6   def ok?
  7     !not_ok?
  8   end
  9
 10   def not_ok?
 11     Checkresult.where(id: most_recent_checkresult_ids).where(status: false).exists?
 12   end
 13
 14
 15
 16   private
 17
 18   def most_recent_checkresult_ids
 19     if @check_ids == nil
 20    Checkresult
 21     .select(:check_id, "MAX(id) as id")
 22     .group(:check_id)
 23     .map { |cr| cr.id }
 24     else
 25    Checkresult
 26     .select(:check_id, "MAX(id) as id")
 27     .where(check_id: @check_ids)
 28     .group(:check_id)
 29     .map { |cr| cr.id }
 30     end
 31   end
 32 end
```

How could i do that? I dont want redundant code and i know there is a way to shorten it but i dont know how.

Comment: Without giving you the exact code, I'd start by thinking what does those queries do and if there are alternatives ways to do it (by looking what you have here, I can say definetely there are). Try to encapsulate the logic in a scope on `Checkresult` and then you'll see the refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this code by limiting the `if` condition to the part that actually varies, rather than repeating a larger section of code.

Also (a minor point), you can use `Symbol#to_proc` to shorted the `map` syntax:

```
def most_recent_checkresult_ids
  check_results = Checkresult.select(:check_id, "MAX(id) as id")
  check_results = check_results.where(check_id: @check_ids) if @check_ids

  check_results.group(:check_id).map(&:id)
end
```

Comment: Instead of `.map(&:id)` you can just use `.ids`.

Comment: Thank you that helped me alot. I used the line where the if statement is at last. Didnt know that worked. Now i have a 3 liner that works and i dont have redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need stateful class and a ton of helpers.

```rb
class OverallStatus
  def self.ok?(check_ids = nil)
    ids = Checkresult.select(:check_id, "MAX(id) as id")
    ids = ids.where(check_id: check_ids) unless check_ids.nil?

    not Checkresult.where(id: ids, status: false).exists?
  end
end
```

And use it as

```rb
OverallStatus.ok?([1, 2, 3])
```